# Is there an Android Barcode Library that has function that can simply be passed a bitmap of the barcode and return the value?

Tags: android, barcode, qr-code

I've looked at Zbar and ZXing and even a few paid libraries but I want something much more portable and simple that I can use without going to a different screen / activity etc.  Open source preferred but I'm sort of desperate here so I'm willing to pay if necessary.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at **commercial** PDF417.mobi:

https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-android/tree/master/Pdf417MobiDemo/pdf417MobiDirectAPIDemo

The DirectAPI supports use case of scanning without going to a new activity.

As shown in the comments the actual example is in this [file](https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-android/blob/master/Pdf417MobiDemo/pdf417MobiDirectAPIDemo/src/main/java/com/microblink/barcode/imagescan/ScanImageActivity.java). When you have bitmap, you can start recognition as shown on this [line](https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-android/blob/master/Pdf417MobiDemo/pdf417MobiDirectAPIDemo/src/main/java/com/microblink/barcode/imagescan/ScanImageActivity.java#L176).

Disclaimer: I worked for the company.

Comment: Thanks, but, it may take me a bit to try this out.  Looking at the code for only about 5 minutes, I couldn't see where I can just pass a bitmap into a method.  I'll probably accept this answer if something better doesn't show up.

Comment: The example is actually shown in [this file](https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-android/blob/master/Pdf417MobiDemo/pdf417MobiDirectAPIDemo/src/main/java/com/microblink/barcode/imagescan/ScanImageActivity.java). When you have bitmap, you can start recognition as shown on [this line](https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-android/blob/master/Pdf417MobiDemo/pdf417MobiDirectAPIDemo/src/main/java/com/microblink/barcode/imagescan/ScanImageActivity.java#L176).